# Interacting with a specific COM DLL

Tags: dll, com

I'm trying to interact with a .dll which will allow me to receive information from a variety of devices (Eye Gaze to be specific). The .dll is called ETUDriver and can be found at http://www.sis.uta.fi/~csolsp/projects.php however it does not come with an accompanying .h file.

I am struggling to actually load, interact and invoke functions from the .dll. A manual is supplied but it is of no help whatsoever with regards to actually setting up the code to start it off. There are three accompanying example apps (with source code) but only two of these work and one of which is in C# so is not helpful. The one that works however loads up the .dll via MFC and this is not a viable option with my code (which is intended to be used with many other projects and as such can't enforce MFC or any other libraries that are not as standard to projects).

Essentially, within the .dll is a series of classes which I need to create within my code and invoke the relevant functions of that class.

I've tried to use `HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(ETUDSink), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, __uuidof(IETUDSink), (LPVOID*)&pETUDSink);
    if(pETUDSink)
    {
        pETUDSink->Start();
    }` however it always returns an error saying that the class is not registered. I can't use MFC to call the relevant .rgs file and am completely stuck on how to get this to work otherwise.

Is there a given format to doing this that I am unaware of and has anyone had experience in using the ETUDriver (or is able to get it working in C++ without use of MFC)?

Thank you for any help you can provide on this subject :)

Comment: class not registered can be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. If you're program is running 32-bit, the COM DLL needs to be registered as 32-bit as well, etc.

Comment: The C++ example app that works has the same project config settings as me and that works fine, what would I need to do to determine/change the 64->32 bit settings of the project?

Comment: This is a configuration in Visual C++. I suppose the ETUDriver is 32-bit. You can check you're 32-bit as well (that should be the default I suppose, here is detailed how to go for 64-bit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h2k70f3s.aspx check you're not configured like this). As Eddy pointed out, you *must* register the ETUDriver, check the accompanying doc. You can do it using regsvr32.exe on your dev machine and use other means (MSI, etc.) for production mode.

Comment: The accompanying doc gives no information regarding registering the .dll. It is extremely lacking in detail relating to integrating the .dll into a custom project.

Comment: Even if it' not mentioned in the doc, you must register a COM object for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the specific DLL in question, but it sounds like you did not register the DLL on the target machine. You can do this by running [regsvr32.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx) or by calling the DLL's exported [DllRegisterServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or by using [side-by-side assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229072%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You need to do register the DLL on each machine that needs to leverage the COM functionality within it, so when you distribute your application, make sure that your installer registers the DLL if you go the regsvr32.exe route.

You can use the [#import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in Microsoft Visual C++ to load the information contained within the DLL without using a header file or rewriting it yourself based on documentation.

Comment: I am developing a .lib helper library to extend functionality of games that include the project. For this reason I can't have each client manually run regsvr32.exe (it should be a fully automated process.

I have used the #import but do not understand how to 'see' what I can actually use within the .dll in terms of classes and functions.

I don't have the source code to the .dll, how would I find out what (or even if) the DLLRegisterServer function exists?

Comment: Use Microsoft's dumpbin utility with the /EXPORTS flag to see the all of the symbols exported by the DLL: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429

Comment: Hi, I have exported the data (http://codepad.org/hdxNSm3A) but I don't really see how I can use any of it? However I noticed that there is a "DLLRegisterServer" in there (line 448 on the link I sent).